# MS Teams mobile: sending and receiving a geolocation

Tags: c#, geolocation, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

Tested on the latest versions of MS Teams for Iphone and Android.

1 MS Teams for Android can send a geolocation for a bot into 1-1 chat, but MS Teams for Iphone doesn't has such option. How can I send a geolacation in Iphone?

Here you see the screenshots from my phone (iPhone 6s, iOS 12.2). 
[image: iphone screens]

2 When a user sends a geolocation to a bot, how can I receive it on the bot's side? I use bot framework v3 and now I have only this:
[image: screenshot]

No ContentUrl, just itemid. Can I download a geolocation by itemid for somehow?

Comment: we are checking it.

Comment: is the location option not visible on iOS? Location can not be the first message on chat. This option will be visible after first message. I see location option on iOS, Can you please check it once again.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT I added some screenshots to my initial post just to make it clear. As you see, in all cases there are messages in the chats, so the location is not the first message. 

I can send the location to a person (1st pic), as a new message on a channel (3rd pic), as a reply to a channel's post (4th pic), but not in 1-1 chat with a bot (2nd pic).

Please, answer my second question too. How can I receive a location on the bot's side?

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT I'm also facing issue receiving geo-location on the bot backend side. I also receive the same html with item id etc attributes. Getting geo-location from user is important for the bot I'm developing. Is it not supported?

Comment: @Abhijit I'm facing the same issue. Location sharing displays for a chat with a User. Location sharing does not display when chatting with a Bot. I am using iPhone Version 2.3.1. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT Any update on this? I just updated to the latest version of iOS (14.4.1) and Microsoft Teams (2.4.2). There is no option to share Location with a Bot. It works fine on Android, though. The geolocation permission has been added to the manifest. I was previously running iOS 12.1.4 with Microsoft Teams (2.3.1). There was no option to share Location with a Bot.